# Replicate Google App Engine app.yaml handlers in PHP outside of GAE

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-app-engine, tomcat, app.yaml

I am considering building my PHP project in Google App Engine (GAE), and I would like to be confident that I could easily port my code to a more standard Apache Tomcat & PHP server if needed. The one aspect that I cannot find a standard implementation for is [GAE's app.yaml handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers). Let me define the functionality that I care about:

> The ability to explicitly route incoming requests to a specific php script for fulfillment based on URL patterns.

My searches thus far have lead me to the Tomcat .htaccess RewriteEngine. However, it seems like this literally re-writes the URL and redirects the client machine to that URL. Am I wrong? Other than this solution, I have found nothing else that is promising. Can someone suggest a replacement for GAE's app.yaml handlers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which lets you setup rewrite rules that are interpreted behinds the scenes and do not change the external URL.